# Use NUnit 3 when a dependency depends on NUnit >= 2.x?

Tags: nunit

NuGet is filled with things that are built with dependency on `NUnit>= 2.x`. Can I use them with `NUnit 3`?

A specific example.

- Create a new .Net project with a TestProject.
- Via NuGet, add dependencies to packages

  - `NUnit`, noting that you're now on version 3
  - `TestBase`, which claims dependency on NUnit (>= 2.6.3)

And create some unit tests. This works until you actually invoke something in TestBase which call NUnit, e.g.

```
1.ShouldBeGreaterThan(0);
```

At this point the version mismatch breaks it.

**"Assembly Binding Redirect!"** I hear you cry. But NUnit 3 is signed with a different public key than Nunit 2, so that isn't possible.

Is it in fact possible to build something with a dependency on `NUnit>= 2.x` that will works with NUnit 3, given a change in public key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NUnit 3 is basically a completely new product. In retrospect, we probably should have created a new NuGet package. Too late now.

Since the 3.0 framework works completely differently from v2, an Assembly redirect would not help you.

Third party products that want to work with NUnit 3.0 usually need to be rewritten unless they only use a very small subset that hasn't changed.

If you want to use NUnit 3 you can only use 3RE party solutions that are updated to work with it.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but I guess it's 'the' answer. ta.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Charlie's answer, I would recommend that people try to contact the authors of broken packages and encourage them to either update their packages to work with NUnit 3, or change their dependencies to be NUnit>=2.x and <2.9.

The NUnit team has been announcing publicly that NUnit 3 would be a breaking change for many years now. Most of the packages that have dependencies on NUnit tend to be test runners or testing extensions, so I would have hoped they would try to keep informed.

Comment: I take your point that updating the dependency to include <2.9 is a relevant step I can take as a package owner.